# flask-admin form: Constrain Value of Field 2 depending on Value of Field 1

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

One feature I have been struggling to implement in flask-admin is when the user edits a form, to constrain the value of Field 2 once Field 1 has been set.

Let me give a simplified example in words (the actual use case is more convoluted). Then I will show a full gist that implements that example, minus the "constrain" feature.

Let's say we have a database that tracks some software "recipes" to output reports in various formats. The `recipe` table of our sample database has two recipes: "Serious Report", "ASCII Art".

To implement each recipe, we choose one among several methods. The `method` table of our database has two methods: "tabulate_results", "pretty_print".

Each method has parameters. The `methodarg` table has two parameter names for "tabulate_results" ("rows", "display_total") and two parameters for "pretty_print" ("embellishment_character", "lines_to_jump").

Now for each of the recipes ("Serious Report", "ASCII Art") we need to provide the value of the arguments of their respective methods ("tabulate_results", "pretty_print").

For each record, the `recipearg` table lets us select a recipe (that's Field 1, for instance "Serious Report") and an argument name (that's Field 2). The problem is that all possible argument names are shown, whereas they need to be constrained based on the value of Field 1.

What filtering / constraining mechanism can we implement such that once we select "Serious Report", we know we will be using the "tabulate_results" method, so that only the "rows" and "display_total" arguments are available?

I'm thinking some AJAX wizardry that checks Field 1 and sets a query for Field 2 values, but have no idea how to proceed.

You can see this by playing with the gist: click on the `Recipe Arg` tab. In the first row ("Serious Report"), if you try to edit the "Methodarg" value by clicking on it, all four argument names are available, instead of just two.

```
# full gist: please run this

from flask import Flask
from flask_admin import Admin
from flask_admin.contrib import sqla
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

# Create application
app = Flask(__name__)

# Create dummy secrey key so we can use sessions
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '123456790'

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///a_sample_database.sqlite'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ECHO'] = True
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

# Create admin app
admin = Admin(app, name="Constrain Values", template_mode='bootstrap3')

# Flask views
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return '<a href="/admin/">Click me to get to Admin!</a>'


class Method(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'method'
    mid = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    method = Column(String(20), nullable=False, unique=True)
    methodarg = relationship('MethodArg', backref='method')
    recipe = relationship('Recipe', backref='method')


    def __str__(self):
        return self.method


class MethodArg(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'methodarg'
    maid = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    mid = Column(ForeignKey('method.mid', ondelete='CASCADE', onupdate='CASCADE'), nullable=False)
    methodarg = Column(String(20), nullable=False, unique=True)
    recipearg = relationship('RecipeArg', backref='methodarg')
    inline_models = (Method,)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.methodarg


class Recipe(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'recipe'
    rid = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    mid = Column(ForeignKey('method.mid', ondelete='CASCADE', onupdate='CASCADE'), nullable=False)
    recipe = Column(String(20), nullable=False, index=True)
    recipearg = relationship('RecipeArg', backref='recipe')
    inline_models = (Method,)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.recipe


class RecipeArg(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'recipearg'

    raid = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    rid = Column(ForeignKey('recipe.rid', ondelete='CASCADE', onupdate='CASCADE'), nullable=False)
    maid = Column(ForeignKey('methodarg.maid', ondelete='CASCADE', onupdate='CASCADE'), nullable=False)
    strvalue = Column(String(80), nullable=False)
    inline_models = (Recipe, MethodArg)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.strvalue


class MethodArgAdmin(sqla.ModelView):
    column_list = ('method', 'methodarg')
    column_editable_list = column_list



class RecipeAdmin(sqla.ModelView):
    column_list = ('recipe', 'method')
    column_editable_list = column_list



class RecipeArgAdmin(sqla.ModelView):
    column_list = ('recipe', 'methodarg', 'strvalue')
    column_editable_list = column_list


admin.add_view(RecipeArgAdmin(RecipeArg, db.session))

# More submenu
admin.add_view(sqla.ModelView(Method, db.session, category='See Other Tables'))
admin.add_view(MethodArgAdmin(MethodArg, db.session, category='See Other Tables'))
admin.add_view(RecipeAdmin(Recipe, db.session, category='See Other Tables'))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    db.drop_all()
    db.create_all()
    db.session.add(Method(mid=1, method='tabulate_results'))
    db.session.add(Method(mid=2, method='pretty_print'))
    db.session.commit()
    db.session.add(MethodArg(maid=1, mid=1, methodarg='rows'))
    db.session.add(MethodArg(maid=2, mid=1, methodarg='display_total'))
    db.session.add(MethodArg(maid=3, mid=2, methodarg='embellishment_character'))
    db.session.add(MethodArg(maid=4, mid=2, methodarg='lines_to_jump'))
    db.session.add(Recipe(rid=1, mid=1, recipe='Serious Report'))
    db.session.add(Recipe(rid=2, mid=2, recipe='ASCII Art'))
    db.session.commit()
    db.session.add(RecipeArg(raid=1, rid=1, maid=2, strvalue='true' ))
    db.session.add(RecipeArg(raid=2, rid=1, maid=1, strvalue='12' ))
    db.session.add(RecipeArg(raid=3, rid=2, maid=4, strvalue='3' ))
    db.session.commit()

    # Start app
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: For flexible database interface this feature one must have. A good answer will help many people. Sure the data itself one can structure differently but that's not the point. Adding bounty. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I see two ways of tacking this problem:

1- When Flask-Admin generate the form, add `data` attributes with the `mid` of each `methodArg` on each `option` tag in the `methodArg` select. Then have some JS code filter the `option` tags based on the recipe selected.

**EDIT**

Here is a tentative try at putting a `data-mid` attribute on each `option`:

```
def monkeypatched_call(self, field, **kwargs):
    kwargs.setdefault('id', field.id)
    if self.multiple:
        kwargs['multiple'] = True
    html = ['<select %s>' % html_params(name=field.name, **kwargs)]
    for (val, label, selected), (_, methodarg) in zip(field.iter_choices(), field._get_object_list()):
        html.append(self.render_option(val, label, selected, **{'data-mid': methodarg.mid}))
    html.append('</select>')
    return HTMLString(''.join(html))

Select.__call__ = monkeypatched_call
```

The blocker is in the fact that those render calls are triggered from the jinja templates, so you are pretty much stuck updating a widget (`Select` being the most low-level one in WTForms, and is used as a base for Flask-Admin's `Select2Field`).

After getting those `data-mid` on each of your options, you can proceed with just binding an `change` on your recipe's select and display the methodarg's `option` that have a matching `data-mid`. Considering Flask-Admin uses `select2`, you might have to do some JS tweaking (easiest ugly solution would be to clean up the widget and re-create it for each `change` event triggered)

Overall, I find this one less robust than the second solution. I kept the monkeypatch to make it clear this should not be used in production imho. (the second solution is slightly less intrusive)

2- Use the supported ajax-completion in Flask-Admin to hack your way into getting the options that you want based on the selected recipe:

First, create a custom AjaxModelLoader that will be responsible for executing the right selection query to the DB:

```
class MethodArgAjaxModelLoader(sqla.ajax.QueryAjaxModelLoader):
    def get_list(self, term, offset=0, limit=10):
        query = self.session.query(self.model).filter_by(mid=term)
        return query.offset(offset).limit(limit).all()

class RecipeArgAdmin(sqla.ModelView):
    column_list = ('recipe', 'methodarg', 'strvalue')
    form_ajax_refs = {
        'methodarg': MethodArgAjaxModelLoader('methodarg', db.session, MethodArg, fields=['methodarg'])
    }
    column_editable_list = column_list
```

Then, update Flask-Admin's `form.js` to get the browser to send you the recipe information instead of the `methodArg` name that needs to be autocompleted. (or you could send both in `query` and do some arg parsing in your AjaxLoader since Flask-Admin does no parsing whatsoever on `query`, expecting it to be a string I suppose [[0]](https://github.com/mrjoes/flask-admin/blob/master/flask_admin/model/base.py#L1577). That way, you would keep the auto-completion)

```
data: function(term, page) {
    return {
        query: $('#recipe').val(),
        offset: (page - 1) * 10,
        limit: 10
    };
},
```

This snippet is taken from Flask-Admin's `form.js` [[1]](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/blob/master/flask_admin/static/admin/js/form.js#L20)

Obviously, this needs some tweaking and parametrising (because doing such a hacky solution would block you from using other ajax-populated select in the rest of your app admin + the update on `form.js` directly like that would make upgrading `Flask-Admin` extremely cumbersome)

Overall, I am unsatisfied with both solutions and this showcase that whenever you want to go out of the tracks of a framework / tool, you can end up in complex dead ends. This might be an interesting feature request / project for someone willing to contribute a **real** solution upstream to Flask-Admin though.

Comment: Will be curious to see #1 if you show working code, +1 for the solutions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Suffering from bad cold right now but looking forward to trying out your ideas (not sure I fully understand the first). You think something along the lines of your first idea would be the most robust? By the way, if you had to guess, is this the kind of feature that should make it into `flask-admin` at some stage?

Comment: Hans Schindler@: I will try to get something working for 1-. My biggest hurdle right now is to get Flask-Admin to add a `data` attribute on the `option` tags.

droptable@: hopefully getting some code for 1 will make it clearer ;) As for the most robust, both are hacks and the 1 has some drawbacks as well: you need to get the list of all methodArgs beforehand so that the JS can have a big enough picture to do the filtering for you. Finally, I am not the maintainer of Flask-Admin, my guess is it's a very difficult feature to get generically enough right and can still be considered an edge case.

Comment: I tried the first solution but it ends up being even more cumbersome as you basically have to hijack WTForms more than Flask-Admin. You could get rid of the monkeypatch by using something like: http://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced/#wysiwig-text-fields (which would also enable you to not have that `data-mid` on every `select` in your page). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23023788/add-a-css-class-to-an-option-in-a-wtforms-selectfield discusses that issue with adding custom attributes to options in a WTForm's `SelectField`.

Comment: Thank you for the terrific effort (accepted), which gets you into the [`flask-admin` hall of fame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flask-admin?sort=votes&pageSize=50) :) This shows that there is no easy way. I hope the `flask-admin` team adds this much-needed feature at some stage. For the time being I'll forget about `flask-admin` and make my interface from the ground up.

Comment: Select.__call__ where Select come from?

Answer (score 1):

There is another easy solution that I made and it works

**1- Create your first select option normally with data loaded on it and add a hook to it which will add js event listener when it selects change like this.**

```
from wtforms import SelectField

form_extra_fields = {
    'streetname': SelectField(
        'streetname',
        coerce=str,
        choices=([street.streetname for street in StreetsMetadata.query.all()]),
        render_kw={'onchange': "myFunction()"}
        )
    }
```

**2- Add a JavaScript URL file to the view you want to use this function in, for example.

```
def render(self, template, **kwargs):
    #using extra js in render method allow use url_for that itself requires an app context

    self.extra_js = [url_for("static", filename="admin/js/users.js")]
    response = render_miror(self, template,**kwargs)
    return response
```

3- Create a role-protected endpoint that you used for this view that will accept a GET request from JS based on the first value specified for the entry, for example this route returns a list of house numbers by querying the street name that came from the first entry

```
@super_admin_permission.require(http_exception=403)
@adminapp.route('/get_houses_numbers')
def gethouses():
    request_data = request.args
    if request_data and 'street' in request_data:
        street = StreetsMetadata.query.filter(StreetsMetadata.streetname == request_data['street']).one_or_none()
        street_houses = lambda:giveMeAllHousesList(street.excluded, street.min, street.max)
        if street_houses:
            return jsonify({'code': 200, 'houses': street_houses()})
        else:
            return jsonify({'code': 404, 'houses': []})
    else:
        return jsonify({'code': 400, 'street': []})
```

now python part completed time for JavaScript

4- We have to define three functions, the first of which will be called when the form build page is loaded and which do two things first,
A dummy select entry will be created using JS and append that entry to the same string input container
Make string entry read-only to improve user experience
Second, it will send a GET request to the specified route to get a list of house numbers using the specified street input value
Then get the result and create the option elements and append these options to the dummy selection, you can also select the first option while appending the options.

**5- The second function "myFunction" is the hook defined in Python in this part**

```
 render_kw={'onchange': "myFunction()"}
```

This function will do nothing new, it will only send a GET request when the first specified input value is changed, send a GET request to get a list of new house numbers based on the given street name input value by doing a query on the database, then dump the inner HTML of the dummy selection entry , then create and append new options to it.

6- The last function is the callback function which listens for the change on the dummy select entry created with JS when the user chooses the house number which will be reflected in the main string entry, finally you can click save and you will see it working

Note that this whole idea I created is not as good as the built in flask admin, but if you are looking for the end goal and without any problems you can use it

My JS code

```
/*
  This Function when run when a form included it will create JS select input with the
  default loaded streetname and add house number on that select this select will used
  to guide creator of the house number or to select the house number
*/
async function onFlaskFormLoad(){

  const streetSelect = document.querySelector("#streetname");
  const checkIfForm = document.querySelector("form.admin-form");
  if (checkIfForm){
    let checkSelect = document.querySelector("#realSelect");
    if (!checkSelect){
      const mySelectBox = document.createElement("select");
      const houseString = document.querySelector("#housenumber");
      const houseStringCont = houseString.parentElement;
      mySelectBox.classList.add("form-control")
      mySelectBox.id = "realSelect";
      houseStringCont.appendChild(mySelectBox);
      mySelectBox.addEventListener("change", customFlaskAdminUnpredefinedSelect);
      houseString.setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
      const res = await fetch(`/get_houses_numbers?street=${streetSelect.value}`);
      const data = await res.json();
      console.log(data);
      if (data.code == 200 && mySelectBox){
        data.houses.forEach( (houseOption, index)=>{
          if (index == 0){
            houseString.value = houseOption;
          }
          let newHouse = document.createElement("option");
          newHouse.setAttribute("value", houseOption);
          newHouse.innerText = houseOption;
          mySelectBox.appendChild(newHouse);
        });
      }


    }
  }
}

onFlaskFormLoad();


/*
  this function will called to change the string input value to my custom js select
  value and then use that string to house number which required by flask-admin
*/
function customFlaskAdminUnpredefinedSelect(){
  const theSelect = document.querySelector("#realSelect");
  const houseString = document.querySelector("#housenumber");
  houseString.value = theSelect.value;
  return true;
}
/*
   flask admin hook that will listen on street input change and then it will send
   get request to secured endpoint with role superadmin required and get the housenumbers
   using the streetname selected and then create options and add to my select input
*/
async function myFunction(){
  const streetSelect = document.querySelector("#streetname");
  const houseString = document.querySelector("#housenumber");
  const houseStringCont = houseString.parentElement;

  const theSelect = document.querySelector("#realSelect");
  const res = await fetch(`/get_houses_numbers?street=${streetSelect.value}`);
  const data = await res.json();
  console.log(data);
  if (data.code == 200 && theSelect){
    theSelect.innerHTML = "";
    data.houses.forEach( (houseOption, index)=>{
      if (index == 0){
        houseString.value = houseOption;
      }
      let newHouse = document.createElement("option");
      newHouse.setAttribute("value", houseOption);
      newHouse.innerText = houseOption;
      theSelect.appendChild(newHouse);
    });
  }
}
```

Now if I change the street name of the first specified input I will get a new list containing the numbers based on the first input value, note if you have a way to create a python field that accepts the non-predefined options then there is no need to create dummy input you can create and append the new options Directly to second select input

final result

[image]

Comment: This answer is awesome and it works. Now I just need to figure out how to get model object instances instead of just form primary key(s) when the form data gets back to the server...